# Find values of C that satisfy the statement of theorem (Rolles/MVT)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following function:

$x^3+x-1$    $[0, 2]$

And determined the following:

$f(0)=0^3+0-1=-1$

$f(2)=2^3+2-1=9$

And then this:

$f'(c)=(9-(-1))/(2-0)$

$f'(c)=3c^2+c-1=5$

And I'm stuck on the above.  I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: By the way, it's $f'(c)=3c^2+c = 5$. Solve the quadratic: $3c^2+c-5=0$ with whichever method you like. Make sure you pick solutions that lie in $[0,2]$.

Comment: Wow.. I cannot believe I made a mistake like that when taking the derivative!  Thanks for the tip!  That was a very noob mistake by me.

Comment: Actually I caught one mistake and missed the other! It's $f'(c)=3c^2+1=5$. It happens to everyone; don't worry.

Comment: Wow, so embarrassing haha... Apparently I only took the derivative of the first term.  I must have been on math overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are looking at the function $x^3 + x - 1$.  You should, by now, know why this is an MVT exercise and not a Rolle's Exercise.  When you take the derivative you get the following
$$
f^{`}(x) = 3x^2 + 1
$$
From here you use the slope of the secant line you found by using the original function to set it equal to the derivative of f and solve for c
$$
f^{`}(c) = 3c^2 + 1 = 5 \implies 3c^2 + 1 = 5 \implies c=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$